# How to remove paragraph By using php

Tags: php

I have paragraph like this

```
<p> 
    <p>This is new content</p>
</p>
```

I want to remove that outer paragraph tag by using php.

how can we remove .can you please explain.

Answer (score 1):

At face value, you can do

`$content = preg_replace('~<p>\s*<p>(.*?)</p>\s*</p>~s','<p>$1</p>',$content);`

here is a [demo](http://regex101.com/r/yG7bG9) (demo has forwardslashes escaped since it uses `/` as delim)

.. but I have a sneaking suspicion your real content is more complex than this...

Comment: this problem occurred in xml file creating.but that tag  not working

Comment: well like I said.. I had a sneaking suspicion your content is more complex than you are portraying...

Comment: in XML,<br> tags are coming.i want to remove that <br> tags .But we have to provide new line to where we deleted that <br> tags ...can you please tell me for this @Crayon Violent

Answer (score 0):

You can use str_replace function. This may not be the correct answer. But it works.

Try this

```
 $string = "<p><p>This is new content</p></p>";
 $string = str_replace("<p><p>","<p>",$string);
 $string = str_replace("</p></p>","</p>",$string);

now      $string will have "<p>This is new content</p>"
```

Comment: this won't work. you can see in his example code there are spaces and linebreaks in-between the tags...

Comment: i know this one.But this not working in creating xml file.I am taking content from database.

Comment: so first remove spaces and lines between two angle braces > < .. and then use my code.. 
Try this

 $string = preg_replace('/>\s+</', '><', $string);
 $string = str_replace("<p><p>","<p>",$string);
 $string = str_replace("</p></p>","</p>",$string);

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

`$str = preg_replace('!<p>(.*?)</p>!Uis', '$1', $str);`

If you provide better context I can provide a better answer. This will take what's inside a pair of `<p></p>` tags and return it. If they are nested `<p>` tags then it will remove a level of nesting. If they arn't nested it will remove the `<p>` tag.

Comment: I modified it to be ungreedy but I don't know if that will solve the problem you are having. If you could show me an example of what doesn't work I could fix it.

Comment: actually i dont have more reputation to show that image..that is xml file .

Answer (score 0):

Replace spaces and line breaks between angle braces and then replace two paragraph tags with one tag.

```
$string = preg_replace('/>\s+</', '><', $string); 
$string = str_replace("<p><p>","<p>",$string); 
$string = str_replace("</p></p>","</p>",$string);
```